# Adding additional linker input dependencies to solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, linker-errors

I am using Visual Studio to develop a C++ project. After switching to Windows 11, I need to add following additional linker input dependencies (`ws2_32.lib`, `bcrypt.lib`) via `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies`. I have many projects inside a solution and all of them need these two libraries. How is it possible to add them at solution level (and not add them for each project)?

Comment: Select all the projects and add them at the same time or create a props file

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I select all projects and click on properties there is no Linker option to change settings.
I use Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019,Version 16.11.5.

How to create props file for this purpose?

Answer (score -1):

You need to press **Ctrl**, and then select the required project (not solution) to add the directory in properties. Also, you could consider using `#pragma comment(lib,"your path/ws2_32.lib")` in every  project.